# how to close the event of a target in jquery?

Tags: jquery, click, handler

I have several menu buttons in menu panel. each button opens a css:box(100px 100px)
Now, when I click on one box it opens ,when I click on an other one I want that one to open the the former one to close simultaneoulsy.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //this is click anywhere function
     $(document).click(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;

    if (!$(target).is('li.faq')) {
        $('#faq_container').hide();
    }
    });
    });
```

Is there a general way i can achieve this ? instead of checking if element in class is open and then selectively closing?

I have used the $('html').click() function but it closes the box even before I get to open it!

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that resets the menu state and call it at the beginning of your click handler.

Something like

```
function clear(){
  $('#faq_container').hide();
  //hide everything else here
}
```

then just clear() before you open the new css box.